# Quickest way to load total number of points within a set of iterations?

Tags: sdk, rally

I am creating an app which graphs the total number of accepted points on an iteration by iteration basis, compared to all points accepted within that iteration (regardless of project). Currently, I am using a WsapiDataStore call with filters to only pull from the chosen iterations. However, this requires pulling all user stories within the iteration and then summing the Plan Estimate fields of each. It works, but it takes a pretty long time (about 20-30 seconds) to pull data which I would assume might be able to be queried in a single call. Am I correct in my thinking, or is this really the easiest way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rally's API does not support server side aggregations. Unfortunately pulling that data into local memory is the only way to do calculations like this.